# showing results of multiple queries in one table

Tags: sql-server-2008

In sql, one query gets one column, other query gets another column and so on, I want to show these multiple columns in one table as multiple columns.

For example:

```
Query1 gives column 'EmployeeId' .........
Query2 gives column 'EmployeeName' .......
Query3 gives column 'EmployeeAddress'
```

Now I want to show these three columns in one table like
table1 has columns `'EmployeeId', 'EmployeeName' and 'EmployeeAddress'`

Since in both Queries it is `ORDER BY EmployeeId` in increasing order, so in final table (table1 here) it gives corresponding Id, name and address.

Basically I need to combine two result sets in one table based on EmployeeId.

Comment: Can you show what you have done? Are these fields not coming from the same table?

Comment: post your 3 queries, so that we will know the joining columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the queries I have no idea how many tables you have or how they link.  But it sounds link you need to join sub queries together to get the result you are after.  Example Below

```
   select emp.empId, ea.EmployeeAddress, en.EmployeeName
   from emp
   left join 
   (
      select empId, EmployeeAddress
      from EmpAddress
   ) ea on ea.empid = emp.empid 
   left join 
   (
      select empId, EmployeeName
  from empNames
   ) en on en.empId = emp.EmpId
   order by emp.empId
```